# Mysql find customers that bought X but not Y

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to determine if a customer has bought a product, but not a specific product.

My database includes 2 tables that we'll need to reference - tblOrders and tblOrderItems

```
tblOrders
OrderID, FirstName, LastName, Email

tblOrderItems
OrderItemID, OrderID, ProductID
```

tblOrders can have or many specific orders to a customer. That will be based on Email for multiple orders by a single person. Each Order can have one or many order items. These are the products related to the order. They are joined by OrderID. ProductID will be joined to tblProducts, but for this question, we can just refer to the ProductID in tblOrderItems.

Basically, let's say I'm looking for people that have never purchased a 'hat'. We sell pants, shirts and hats.

Johnny B bought a pair of pants in January, he bought a shirt in February so I would need his record to show as never buying a hat.

Janie C bought a pair of pants in January, she bought a hat in February and a shirt in March. She should not come up in the result.

Bill W. bought a pair of pants and a shirt in a single order (multiple items), so I would need his record to show as never buying a hat.

I can get the single order with multiple items to work, but I have problems with multiple orders in the past. I basically want to get a unique (group by) of emails that have never bought hats.

Comment: Hint:  `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: You wish to show a list of customers whose distinct clothing-item-type purchase history count is less than the total distinct clothing-item-type count in your store? I.e. you sell 27 broad categories of things and you wish to see a list of customers who have purchased between 1 and 26 different types of things?

Comment: I ask because you seem to start out giving a hat as an example of a type of product that someone might not have bought, but you finish up saying you definitely want a list of people who've never bought a hat. What about Sarah, who bought a shirt and a hat but no pants? (apart from the obvious stir she might cause when she goes for a walk) ;)

Comment: Hello Caius, yes, I want all people that have never bought a hat. That would include past history (individual order with single order item) or with an order with multiple order items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I basically want to get a unique (group by) of emails that have never bought hats."

Just translate that into a query

```
select o.emailid
  from tblOrders o
  join tblOrderItems oi
    on o.orderid=oi.orderid
group by o.emailid
having count(case when oi.productid=<product_id_of_hat> then 1 end)=0
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks! Didn't think about HAVING COUNT!